# Get complete video stats using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to use the Youtube API to get complete stats about a video?

I am talking about the history of daily views, as it can be seen on a video page by clicking on "... More" and on "Statistics".

Comment: Try Googling the YouTube analytics api

Comment: I don't want stats about my videos but about other people's videos.

Comment: No you cant do that Videos.search returns https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource which doesn't contain any stats.